# Prevent multiple unintXXX.exe file during update

Tags: inno-setup

What is the correct way to update existing setup?
Now, when I'm updating (installing on an existing setup) the setup creating another uninstall exe file for each time I install.

The AppId is the same.

Thanks

Comment: That's fine. It is the uninstall log for each version (instance) of the setup that you run.

Comment: @TLama thanks.
I removed the `UninstallLogMode` parameter and it solved the problem.